# Извлечь содержимое тега <a> с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Нужно вытащить из ссылки имя и фамилию с помощью `RegEx`:

```html
<a href="/authors/153612.html">Сергей Драгун</a>
```

Цифры после `authors` динамически меняются.

Comment: Почему бы не взять нормальный html-парсер?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/SoAOgu/1 если совсем топорно, то вот так `[^А-ЯЁа-яё]+([А-Яа-яЁё]+\s[А-Яа-яЁё]+)` иначе нужно больше примеров и вывод того что хотите.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags >_>

Answer (score 0):

Вот так вот:

```
(?<=<a href="\/authors\/\d+\.html">)[а-яёА-ЯЁ]+ [а-яёА-ЯЁ]+(?=<\/a>)
```

Тест https://regexr.com/59eob

> <a href="/authors/153612.html">**Сергей Драгун**</a>
>
> <a href="/authors/23151512.html">**Иван Иванов**</a>

Comment: Только когда я добавляю эту регулярку, она из всех ссылок вырезает слова, а мне нужно чтобы из ссылок такого вида именно как кинул, потому что авторы на всех страницах одинаково задаются.
/authors/ - это в ссылках не меняется, меняются только цифры.

Comment: @almaxxx изменил, давайте правильное условие сразу в следующий раз

Answer (score 0):

Держите:

```
<a href="/authors/153612.html">Сергей Драгун</a>

/>([а-яА-Я\s]+)</ig
```

Comment: Так эта регулярка и `<` с `>` находит. Да и букв `ёЁ` нет